# Consistent rotation on click as opposed to drag

Tags: three.js

I'm probably missing something to get this done.

https://codepen.io/ndsp/pen/YQavxG

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>three.js webgl - materials - cube reflection [cars]</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r83/three.js"></script>
    <script>

        var controls, camera, scene, renderer;
        var cameraCube, sceneCube;
        var textureCube;
        var cubeMesh;
        var currentLookat, newLookat;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {
            // CAMERAS
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 0, 1000 );
            cameraCube = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000 );

            currentLookat = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, - 1 );
            newLookat = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, - 1 );

            // SCENE
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            sceneCube = new THREE.Scene();

            // Lights
            var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
            scene.add( ambient );

            var starsGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

            for ( var i = 0; i < 1000; i ++ ) {

                var star = new THREE.Vector3();
                star.x = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 5000 );
                star.y = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 5000 );
                star.z = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread( 5000 );

                starsGeometry.vertices.push( star )

            }

            var starsMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { color: 0x888888 } )

            var starField = new THREE.Points( starsGeometry, starsMaterial );

            scene.add( starField );


            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 10);
            var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

            cube.position.z = 20;
            cube.position.y = 10;

            scene.add( cube );


            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.autoClear = false;
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer.setFaceCulling( THREE.CullFaceNone );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        }


        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            cameraCube.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            cameraCube.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }


        function animate() {
            currentLookat.lerp(newLookat, 0.05);
            camera.lookAt(currentLookat);
            // controls.update();
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }


        function render() {
            var timer = -0.0002 * Date.now();
            cameraCube.rotation.copy( camera.rotation );
            renderer.render( sceneCube, cameraCube );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }


        function onMouseDown( event ) {


            var canvasPosition = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();

            var mouseX = event.clientX - canvasPosition.left;
            var mouseY = event.clientY - canvasPosition.top;

            var mouseVector = new THREE.Vector3 (
                            2 * (mouseX / window.innerWidth) - 1,
                    1 - 2 * (mouseY / window.innerHeight), 1);

            console.log(mouseVector);
            mouseVector.unproject( camera );
            console.log(mouseVector);
            // console.log(unproject( camera ));
            var dir = mouseVector.sub( camera.position ).normalize();
            var distance = - camera.position.z / dir.z;
            var oldPos = camera.position.clone();
            newLookat = camera.position.clone().add( dir.multiplyScalar( distance ) );

            currentLookat.applyQuaternion( camera.quaternion );

        }

        window.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onMouseDown, false );
    </script>

</body>
```

The idea is to click an area in space and rotate the camera (or camera lookat) to that point based on the mouse coordinates to world coordinates thing that is going on in the example. the smaller the interpolation factor in lerp, the more pronounced the inaccurate rotation presents itself.

I tried passing both matrices and vectors into lerp, but I get the exact same behavior. Without lerp, it doesn't look like the problem exists, although it's hard to tell.

I need help just to diagnose, let alone fix it.

Related to this: [Tween question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763104/tween-camera-target-in-three-js) but I wanted to eliminate tween.js, partially on comments I received there.

Thank you!

Comment: Your codepen link is broken. Rather than using codepen, please include [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your post (code blocks, or a snippet). When your codepen link goes away, so does the context of your question.

Comment: I have fixed it and added code. Thank you.